# Check programmatically created UIView visible or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

```
vwInfo = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 85, 280, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:vwInfo];
```

I create a UIView programmatically on button tap.when i click it again i need to check vwInfo is visible or not.I can done this with a Boolean value.is there any other option to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if view is exist or not using `isDescendantOfView` but make sure you have to pass your `vwInfo`'s superview to check view already exist or not.

```
if ([vwInfo isDescendantOfView:self.view]) {
    //view already exist in self.view
}
else{
   //view is not exist in self.view.
}
```

Comment: @user3823935 if answer is helpful then upvote or mark it as an answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you do not want to add the UIView a second time when you already added it ?
In this case you could declare in your .h(header) file `UIView *vwInfo;`
and then in your `IBAction` for your `UIButton`:

```
if(vwInfo == nil) {
   vwInfo = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 85, 280, 100)];
   [self.view addSubview:vwInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with `Tag` `Functionality`. Assign `tag` to your `view`.

```
UIView * vwInfo = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 85, 280, 100)];
[vwInfo setTag:101];
[self.view addSubview:vwInfo];
```

On `Button Click`

```
- (void)buttonClick :(id)sender {

    UIView * viewTemp = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:101];

    if(viewTemp){
        NSLog(@"View is available");
        if([viewTemp isHidden]){
            NSLog(@"Your view is hidden");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Your view is visible");
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"View is not added yet");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView  is accessible with the superview property

if([vwInfo superview]!=nil)

```
NSLog(@"visible");
```

else

```
NSLog(@"not visible");
```